# AWS ELB SSL - Load Balancing on AWS with a mix of non SSL & SSL enabled sites

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services

Using an AWS ELB - Load Balancer with a number of sites that don't use SSL.

I now have a site that I want to add SSL to.

Can I run both through the same ELB? eg: many sites just using port 80 and one that is using port 443 with SSL that is terminated at the ELB?

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You just add another listener to the ELB. Add a listener with the following properties:

Load Balancer Protocol:  HTTPS
Load Balancer Port: 443
Instance Protocol: HTTPS
Instance Port: 443
SSL Certificate: You will have to upload your certificate to IAM either through the console during listener creation, or beforehand via the IAM API.

Note that your server does not need to have the public facing certificate installed.  A self-signed one will do fine.

Comment: great - thankyou for you time... :)

Comment: have you figured out how to upload the self signed certificate and make it work with elb? I've been struggling with this. Here's my original question on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754089/trouble-getting-https-to-work-with-self-signed-certificate-on-aws-elastic-load-b